# Extracting percentage distribution of values within a raster, from a polygon subset

Tags: r, r-raster, r-sf

I have a raster and `sf` polygon as follows:

```
library(raster)
libary(sf)

# Create raster r
r = raster(ncol=1000, nrow=1000, xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=1000)
values(r) = round(runif(ncell(r),1,10))

# Create sf polygon
poly_sf = st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,10,50,100,0),c(0,70,300,500,0)))))
```

The raster contains cells of values between 1 and 10. I'd like to be able to generate a dataframe that contains the overall percentage of total cells for each value, within a subset of raster cells generated by the polygon `poly_sf`. I've looked at `exactextractr` but haven't figured out how to achieve what I want using that package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the use of `mask` function from `raster` package but you need to convert your polygon into an `sf` object:

```r
library(raster)
library(sf)

# Create raster r
r = raster(ncol=1000, nrow=1000, xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=1000)
values(r) = round(runif(ncell(r),1,10))

# Create sf polygon
poly_sf = st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,10,50,100,0),c(0,70,300,500,0)))))
p2 <- st_as_sf(poly_sf)

# Plot the raster object:
plot(r)
```

[image]

You can create a mask using the `mask` function:

```r
plot(mask(r, p2))
```

[image]

So, to extract values from this masked object, you can use `mask` function and count for proportions of each values using `table`:

```r
# Subset the polyfon from the SF object: 
subset_ra <- mask(r, p2)

# Calculate the porportion of each value
df <- as.data.frame(table(as.matrix(subset_ra)))
df$Percent <- df$Freq / sum(df$Freq) * 100

   Var1 Freq   Percent
1     1  154  5.517736
2     2  329 11.787890
3     3  287 10.283053
4     4  290 10.390541
5     5  325 11.644572
6     6  305 10.927983
7     7  319 11.429595
8     8  312 11.178789
9     9  315 11.286277
10   10  155  5.553565
```

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Yes. It did! When I tried `crop(r, p2) %>% hist(plot=F, breaks = c(1:10))` I achieve the same thing, and it's quicker (for my problem at least). But I don't understand why...

Comment: You're welcome. But be cautious with `crop` because if you look at the output of `hist` (`$counts`, you can see that the number are much much higher that using `mask`.. So, I think using `crop` make the opposite side.

Comment: raster::crop will reduce the extent of a raster to bounding box of another object, while raster::mask will select only the cells within a specific masking object (and keep the original extent). The result will be equivalent in a special case of a rectangular mask, where the mask and its bounding box are equal - but this is not guaranteed, co proceed with caution

Comment: Thanks for this explanation ! Indeed you're right,`crop` get a rectangular box with boundaries of the second object. That's also why I include the graphic representation of the output of `mask`.

Comment: This method works when the mask `sf` object is one single geometry, but how can this be applied in an object with multiple geometries?